# android no notification popup in statusbar

Tags: android, android-notifications

there're two problems here. I try to let user select a **specific time** to make app reminder users to use app. Once user set up a time say 8:00 pm. The notification should pop up every day. However,  After I used

```
"NotificationManager" and "Notification"
```

first of all, there's nothing pop-up. For example, now is 1:19 am in AU, then, i set-up this app to 1:20 am to display the notification in the status bar as a test.

Secondly, if in my **TabBar** class i use

```
nm.cancel(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NotifID"));
```

It will get a null pointer exception

**Here is my code:**

TabBar.class

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.cancel(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NotifID"));
```

Notification.class

```
package com.example.tabpro;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class SettingNotification extends Activity{

TimePicker timePicker;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.setting_notification);

     Button btnset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetAlarm);
     btnset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker_settime);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.tabpro.DisplayNotification");
            Intent i2 = new Intent(SettingNotification.this, TabBar.class);
            i.putExtra("NotifID", 1);                                

            PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getBaseContext(), 0, i, 0); 

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);
            startActivity(i2);

        }


     });



 }


}
```

DisplayNotification.class

```
package com.example.tabpro;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DisplayNotification extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     int notifID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("NotifID");

     Intent i = new Intent("com.example.tabpro.TabBar");

     i.putExtra("NotifID", notifID); 

     PendingIntent detailsIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

     NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Time's up!", System.currentTimeMillis());

     CharSequence from = "AlarmManager - Time's up!";
     CharSequence message = "This is your alert, courtesy of the AlarmManager";        
     notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, detailsIntent);       

     finish();
 }

}
```

Comment: Using `set()` can give you a time in the past, if the hour/minute/second is in today's past. You need to check this and add a day if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`notify()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.app.Notification%29) on your `NotificationManager` to actually show the Notification. Since you never call this method, your Notification is never shown.

Your NullPointerException is likely a different problem. For that, you should do some debugging yourself. First, you need to determine what is null. Then determine why it is null and fix it. In your code, the most likely candidates for causing the NPE in `TabBar` are `nm`, `getIntent()`, and `getExtras()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :
You need to call notify() method to display notification in your notification tray of your device.

Below is the code for that:

```
Notification notification;
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,new Intent(context,      YourActivity.class), 0);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(yourappname).setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(yourappname)
                .setContentText(yourmessage).build();
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```